# Adding button in Android Bottom toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

Is it possible to add button on android bottom tool-bar
which has the icons(back , home , minimize)
and control the color of that icon as well

Thanks
Himanshu

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot add buttons to the navigation bar. This bar is system controlled.

The only thing you can 'add' is the menu button, if the device has soft keys. For this, you'd just need to create a menu in your activity / fragment.

Comment: What do you mean from system controlled , I wanted to know from android source code perspective.Can we tweak in source code and provide this functionality

Comment: as I stated: no, you cannot. Since apps run with user permissions you cannot alter it